# What is the best way to map a Many to Many relationship in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nosql

I am building an immunization tracker.
There are 2 models:

1. patient
2. vaccine

Each patient should have a set of vaccines which can be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Mongo Blog for relationships best way of representing sql many to many is to keep relation ship array in the parent model (one-to-many approach with reference id)
and use that array to for both way data joining.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/